# Java JDBC: MySQL write Out of Memory

Tags: java, mysql

Where is the memory leak in this code? This function is executed millions of times with an extensive usage of memory, causing an out of memory exception after 2.4million execusions.

```
public static void saveCall(Call call) {
        conn = getInstance();

        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                calendar.setTime(call.getDate());
                String sql = "INSERT INTO Calls(id, datetime, duration, customer_phone_id, partner_phone_id) "
                        + "VALUES(null, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn
                        .prepareStatement(sql);
                preparedStatement.setString(1, dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
                preparedStatement.setLong(2, call.getDuration());
                preparedStatement.setLong(3, call.getPhone().getPhoneNumber());
                preparedStatement.setLong(4, call.getPhonePartner()
                        .getPhoneNumber());

                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You may try to close your `PreparedStatement`s. Also, Could you please show us your `getInstance`?

Comment: Closing the PreparedStatement fixed it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. You may also end up using Connection Pool. I'm not a fan of `getInstance` method at all. Are you sure that your connection will be closed?

Comment: @lifus - if `getInstance()` uses the same connection over and over again, it does not matter.  Lets assume that he has really fixed the problem ... rather than attempting to redesign his entire application without seeing the source code :-)

Comment: @StephenC - thats right, it was more like a tip. If 1)`getInstance` is able to handle situations when connection is no longer valid and 2)there is no need in several connections then i'm ok with it. I just wasn't sure that `PreparedStament`s are the only objects to blame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My two cents

[JDBC is tricky](http://lpar.ath0.com/2008/09/05/java-jdbc-and-memory-leaks/).

In this case, `PreparedStatement` should be closed in order to avoid resource leak.

```
public static void saveCall(Call call) {
    conn = getInstance();

    if (conn != null) {
        calendar.setTime(call.getDate());
        String sql = "INSERT INTO Calls(id, datetime, duration, customer_phone_id, partner_phone_id) "
                    + "VALUES(null, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;            
        try {               
            conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
            preparedStatement.setLong(2, call.getDuration());
            preparedStatement.setLong(3, call.getPhone().getPhoneNumber());
            preparedStatement.setLong(4, call.getPhonePartner()
                    .getPhoneNumber());

            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (preparedStatement != null) {
                preparedStatement.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is Java 7 solution:

```
public static void saveCall(Call call) {
    conn = getInstance();

    if (conn != null) {
        calendar.setTime(call.getDate());
        String sql = "INSERT INTO Calls(id, datetime, duration, customer_phone_id, partner_phone_id) "
                    + "VALUES(null, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {                
            preparedStatement.setString(1, dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
            preparedStatement.setLong(2, call.getDuration());
            preparedStatement.setLong(3, call.getPhone().getPhoneNumber());
            preparedStatement.setLong(4, call.getPhonePartner()
                    .getPhoneNumber());

            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your program make an extensive memory usage, there might be no leak but only a garbage collector problem.
IE, your garbage came too late to free some space for creating new objects.

From here, you might want to profile your code when running your queries (visualvm or jconsole provided with any jdk).
You shall see how your memory space is filled (garbage behavior and objects size).

Then, if needed, you will need to configure your jvm garbage collection
The extensive documentation is here : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html
If you share your memory profile, we might help you configure it.

EDIT : There was a memory leak and I was wrong ;-)

Comment: Yeah, `close` methods are there for a reason. GC's are great but not quite great enough to handle resource leaks.

Answer (score 0):

@Pascal Bayer : you should CLOSE your connections after the SQL operations. The modified code with close() would look something like the one below.

```
public static void saveCall(Call call) {
        conn = getInstance();

        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                calendar.setTime(call.getDate());
                String sql = "INSERT INTO Calls(id, datetime, duration, customer_phone_id, partner_phone_id) "
                        + "VALUES(null, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn
                        .prepareStatement(sql);
                preparedStatement.setString(1, dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
                preparedStatement.setLong(2, call.getDuration());
                preparedStatement.setLong(3, call.getPhone().getPhoneNumber());
                preparedStatement.setLong(4, call.getPhonePartner()
                        .getPhoneNumber());

                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
              // good practice of closing connections as soon as 
              // the SQL operations are       completed
              if(!conn.isClosed())
                conn.close();
            }
        }
}
```

Cheers,
Madhu.